# Vue.js: Dynamically add id to href element

Tags: html, css, vue.js, bootstrap-4

I am a beginner.

I am trying to dynamically add id in my href tag but it is not working.

Here is my code.

```
  <div class="col-md-6"  v-for="Product in data">
      <div class="panel panel-default" >
          <div class="panel-heading">
              {{ Product.name }}
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body" v-for = "Category in Product.Categories">
              <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
                  <div class="panel panel-default">
                      <div class="panel-heading">
                          <h4 class="panel-title">

                              <!--SEE HREF BELOW -->
                              <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#{{Category._id}}"  >
                                   {{ Category.name }}</a>
                           </h4>
                       </div>

                       <!-- SEE ID BELOW AS WELL -->
                       <div id="{{ Category._id }}" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                           <div class="panel-body"></div>
                       </div>
                 </div>
            </div>    
       </div>
 </div>
```

I am trying to give _id to href in `<a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#{{Category._id}}">` and in href I am giving Id of `<div id="{{ Category._id }}" class="panel-collapse collapse">` tag on above href.

How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this out: 
`` :href="`#${Category._id}`" ``

The colon tells Vue to interpret the value as JavaScript, not a string.
The backticks are doing string interpolation so you can have the preceding hash.

Comment: Tried but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use interpolation in vue 2, you need to bind your properties to some data object or computed using [v-bind](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Attributes) (or the colon shorthand) for:

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#{{Category._id}}"  >
```

I would use a [computed](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html):

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  computed:{
    href(){
      return '#' + this.Category._id
    }
  },
  data(){
    return {
      Category: {
        _id: 1
      }
    }
  }
})
```

You would then do:

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" v-bind:href="href">
```

Here's a JSFiddle to show you: https://jsfiddle.net/ym29dd2n/

For:

```
<div id="{{ Category._id }}" class="panel-collapse collapse">
```

it's the same thing but you can just bind the id directly:

```
<div v-bind:id="Category._id" class="panel-collapse collapse">
```